# необычный стиль border

Tags: html, css

можно ли как-то реализовать border как на скриншоте? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если нужно реализовать, то приступайте. Мы не можем Вам это запретить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось как-то так. Надеюсь разберётесь.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -21px;
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white; /* по цвету заднего фона */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Есть ещё способы через clip-path или с помощью SVG. Но я не умею

Comment: прикольно. но через `clip-path` действительно намного проще. https://cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/

Comment: @Meth0d наверняка. Просто я не верстальщик) Знаю css так...слегка))